# Samba - write access denied

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I have searched and searched.  Yet, I cannot seem to find an answer and make this work.

Setup:  A single samba share.

```
[myuser]
wide links = yes
path = /home/myuser
public = no
writable = yes
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0770
force user = myuser
force group = myuser
available = yes
write list = myuser
```

Created a samba user:

```
smbpasswd myuser
[entered password twice]
```

I then browse the share, and authenticate.
I try to delete or modify files and I get denied due to access permissions.
Seems simple and straight forward, but there is something I am missing and I'm just not sure what.

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
create mask = 0770
```

Also , add this in your [global] config:

```
security = user
map to guest = Bad Password
```

Comment: Thanks! That does allow me to edit files, but I cannot remove them. But this was a huge improvement.

Comment: @jagauthier : I have edited the answer . Can you add those config and try please.